# How to force load c# cefsharp selenium browser to a desktop version?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing my selenium chrome browser to a website. It is acting as if it's the mobile version of the website, can someone help me or show me or point me in the direction to force load the desktop version of the website? Below is my code:

```
        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            // Create a browser component
            //chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("apps.facebook.com/warcommander");
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("kixeye.com/game/warcommander");
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            //FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chromeBrowser.FrameLoadStart += ChromeBrowser_FrameLoadStart;
        }
```

I have tried loading the default profile; for which I am also having issues with and so there has to be another way to force load the webpage as a desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have found the issue, as the issue was https and it was trying to load something else.

Comment: Make sure you accept your own answer so the question doesn't get left unanswered.